# Flash As2 Image snapshot

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

Is there any approach to take the snapshot of a drawing created in pure AS2 flash coding ?
I tried to use Bitmapdata and bridge but bitmap works in as3 and bridge combines two swf together and communicate with them.

Is there a way of doing screenshot in as2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done in AS2, but it will be a lot slower than in AS3.

Here is an old pre-AS3 example:

http://www.flash-db.com/Tutorials/snapshot/index.php